# Can't approve edit to move examples and delete topic

Tags: bug, documentation

I'm trying to approve [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/52720?draftId=44930), which moves the examples in the "Blame" topic to the "Blaming" topic, then deletes the Blame topic.

Clicking "approve" on the target ("Blaming") seems to have worked, but trying to approve the source edit (on "Blame") gives a 500 error and the "an error has occurred during submission" box.

Chrome 51.0.x on OS X, request `e206be1c-2271-4827-9236-431a585c4041`.

Comment: For the record, I could not reproduce locally

Comment: I can [reproduce it](http://imgur.com/a/oGkSw) On Google Chrome 51.0.2704.103 running on Mac OS X